# customising default Navigation edit button(How do i maintain its state ?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have navigation bar on which i set an default edit button, which lets me to delete the table items. However when my table is empty it still maintains the state of button as "done" and doesnt get back to "edit"
my code goes here, 
In viewDidLoad

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 //My Editing method 
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
 { 
    if([userInfoArr count]!=0)
    {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES]; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: my code goes here, 

In viewDidLoad 
`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`

My Editing method

`-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   if([userInfoArr count]!=0)
   {
       [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
      [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
   }
}`

Comment: @jgdGuy..Use the edit option and add the code to question

Comment: So you want to auto cancel the edit mode when all items have been deleted?

Comment: @LithuT.V will take care of it....

Comment: @Wain yeaaa i wanna autocancel the edit mode..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran in to this problem. I solved this my little hack in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check if datasource is empty. Set the editing to `NO`

```
 [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
 [self setEditing:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Do the deletion...
    }

    // If the array is empty, turn off edit mode
    if ([userInfoArr count] < 1) {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you delete last table item just call

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

to set table view in non-editing mode.

maybe you need to call `[super setEditing:NO animated:YES];` to set button in "edit" state

Comment: Awesome it works..! I had to put this in my numberOfRowsInSection,

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(userInfoArr.count==0)
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
        return userInfoArr.count;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Awesome it works..! I had to put this in my numberOfRowsInSection, `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ if(userInfoArr.count==0)
 { [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES]; [super setEditing:NO animated:YES]; 
} return userInfoArr.count; 
}`